# How to use Gradle Java Api 6.1.1

Tags: java, gradle

I am really confuse on how to use the gradle Java API. I am afraid that my confusion is at the fundamentals of what is this API for.

Basically what I thought I could do with this API was to create a Project object from a build.gradle file and then navigate it programatically through java code to inspect Tasks, Dependencies and so on.

My confusion is that most of what I can see in that library are interfaces and no way to actually create this Project instance (at least that I couldn't find). Not sure if all those interfaces and then use internally by gradle and are not mean to use as I intend.

I am aware that I can actually create tasks in the gradle file to print dependencies for example, but I was just trying to get this via API.
I have also seen the Toolong API, but then again, I do not get the purpose of the actual gradle Java API.

As a reference, this is the project interface I am talking about: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html

Is it possible to navigate this object programatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically what I thought I could do with this API was to create a Project object from a build.gradle file and then navigate it programatically through java code to inspect Tasks, Dependencies and so on.

The ***public*** Gradle API is designed for interacting with either:

- [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) -- `build.gradle`
- [`Settings`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html) -- `settings.gradle`
- [`Gradle`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html) -- `init.gradle`

You will never (as far as I know) create either of those programmatically. They are created for you as soon as you invoke `./gradlew`.

Gradle's [TestKit](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html#test_kit) allows you to create a `Project` instance, but as the name implies it is for **tests** only.

> My confusion is that most of what I can see in that library are interfaces and no way to actually create this Project instance (at least that I couldn't find). Not sure if all those interfaces and then use internally by Gradle and are not mean to use as I intend.

You implement the [`Plugin<T>`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Plugin.html) interface for what you want to configure. `T` being either `Project`, `Settings`, or `Gradle`.

Public APIs generally have the following package convention: `org.gradle.api.*`. These are the ones you should strive to always use. How you use them is *usually* documented somewhere in the Gradle docs' **Authoring Gradle Builds** section: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html

Typically, for most simple plugins, you will only interact with:

- [`Plugin<T>`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Plugin.html) -- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html
- [`DefaultTask`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DefaultTask.html) -- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html

***Private*** APIs generally have the following package convention: `org.gradle.api.internal`. Generally you should avoid using these APIs unless you have a specific reason to. It is in these APIs where `Project`, `Settings`, and `Gradle` instances is created behind the scenes programmatically.

> Is it possible to navigate this object programatically?

Yes. Implement the above `Plugin<T>` interface for the object you wish to interact with. Then apply the plugin to your project.

Comment: Ey man, sorry for this huge delay. I started to work on this as a side project but then priorities changed and was forced to leave it for a while. Then I totally forgot.
Four months of delay is almost unforgivable but I felt obliged to aplogise.

I have time to come back to this and was checking your reply. Thanks for the advise. I think that implementing Plugin<Project> will work to parse it and get what I need out of the build.gradle.
That is what I was not understanding properly. Thanks for your help and sorry again